# How to capture the selected values on a slicer using DAX on Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a slicer filter and I wanna capture de selected values, how can I do this?

I wanna use this values on a measure.

Comment: check this **[power bi measure based on slicer](https://debug.to/890/power-bi-measure-based-on-slicer)**

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [`VALUES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/values-function-dax) and [`SELECTEDVALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function) functions are for.

These references may help further:

[The Many Faces of VALUES](https://powerpivotpro.com/2014/08/the-many-faces-of-values/)

[Using the SELECTEDVALUE Function in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-the-selectedvalue-function-in-dax/)

Comment: Hey Alexis! Thanks for answering. I already read this articles, but I have the following question.

I need to make a measure that returns a `SUM` of **unselected values**, for this, I have a `SUM` of total and wanna remove the `SUM` of **selected values**, I think I need to make another question being more specific, can you help me?

Comment: Yes, please make a separate question for that.

Comment: Alexis! Writing my problem to you makes me understand my own problem and solutionate it. It's very simple by the way.
Thanks for willing to help me!